# QSerialPort continuous reading accumulative delay

Tags: c++, qt, arduino

I am trying to do communication from QT Application to Arduino. The flow is like this: QT Application sends a '1' and Arduino is expected to respond with some data(the data String length is huge, around 300). QT Application is sending '1' at the rate of around 5Hz(every 200ms).

The problem I am facing is, there is an accumulative delay between the Arduino to QT communication. That is, the data I receive from Arduino is not recent data but the frequency of data coming of Arduino is 5Hz only(which is as expected), just the data coming is not recent. This delay keeps on increasing with time. I believe there is some problem with buffer or something.

What I tried:

`QSerialPort serialPort;` is my device port

1. `serialPort.clear()`
2. `serialPort.flush()`
3. Increasing and decreasing Baud Rate from both ends.
4. Reduce character length from Arduino, here delay reduces significantly but the accumulated delay is observed after a long time.

to clear serial communication buffer, but the issue still persists.

Here is my code snippet:

```
connect(timer_getdat, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Rec()));
        timer_getdat->start(200);
```

where `Rec()` is the function where I do communication part.

In `Rec()`:

```
serialPort.write("1", 2);
//            serialPort.waitForBytesWritten(100);

long long bytes_available = serialPort.bytesAvailable();

if (bytes_available >= 1)
{
            serialPort.readLine(temp, 500);
            serialPort.flush(); // no change
            serialPort.clear(); // no change by .clear() also
}
```

I have been stuck on this issue for a quite long time. The above code snippet is what I think is necessary but if anyone needs more clarification, I may reveal more of the code.

Comment: What's the current speed of the serial port?  Can it keep up with: _"...String length is huge, around 300 [no units]..."_ amount of data?

Comment: Reduced it to 100 char long, which is not long I guess for Baud rate of 18400, still doesn't work.

Comment: ok, when I increase Baud rate, the delay significantly reduces but the accumulated delay is reflected after a long time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered with the same issue, and yes `QSerialPort.clear()` and `QSerialPort.flush()` doesn't help. Try doing `readAll()`

So change the part in your Rec() function to something like this:

```
serialPort.write("1", 2);
long long bytes_available = serialPort.bytesAvailable();

if (bytes_available >= 1)
{
            serialPort.readLine(temp, 500);
            serialPort.readAll(); // This reads all the data in buffer at once and clears the queue.
}
```

Even on QT forums, I didn't find the answer to this, was playing with all functions available with QSerialPort class and readAll() seems to work.

About `readAll()`, Qt documentation says:

> Reads all remaining data from the device, and returns it as a byte
>   array.

My explanation for the resolution is that readAll captures all of the data from the communication buffer and empties it.

This should be the job of `clear()` function but apparently `readAll()` seems to work.

Comment: Will check it out and check if there's any accumulative delay.

Comment: because maybe readAll() waits for incoming bytes and clear() only clears the recieve buffer?